# How to wait for entire template to render in KnockoutJS?

Tags: templates, knockout.js

Is there a way in KnockoutJS to have a callback fire when an entire template has finished rendering?

I understand that there is the `afterRender` option which you can use:

```
"template: { name: 'Template', afterRender : myCallback}"
```

But the callback fires twice in my test page (I'm not using `foreach` nor do I have a collection of data to display).

I've seen the following question which is similar to what I'm asking:

[KnockoutJS bind event after template render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306177/knockoutjs-bind-event-after-template-render)

But the answer in that question did not help me out.

Is there an event in Knockout which fires after the entire template has finished rendering, not just after each element which KO finds?

EDIT:
Damn, in my hurry to post this question, I forgot to mention that I'm using this to load the templates:

https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine

Since the templates are stored in external files.

Comment: Maybe you could share a sample  `afterRender` is the proper hook to use in this case.

Comment: Could you expand on your comment please, as I'm not quite sure what you mean? Sorry for being a bit slow here, been a long day!

Comment: Just wondering if you could share your code where the callback is firing twice in a non-foreach scenario, so I could help you further.  `afterRender` is the right hook that you should be looking to use.  Here is a sample: http://jsbin.com/umewov/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: I will post my code ASAP. I will be going out for the evening.

Comment: OK, I've got a plan B which is to edit the infuser config settings to something like `infuser.defaults.ajax.async = false`

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to (quickly) find the entry on github that explains this further, but afaik the reason it renders twice is a bug. My local copy of the external template engine has an additional "self" on line 22, which fixed it.

Instead of

```
options.afterRender = function() {
```

use this

```
self.options.afterRender = function() {
```

And be aware that the version in NuGet seems to be outdated, the GitHub version already has this bugfix included.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning knockout with external templates (same library as you) and mine is also firing twice.

The reason is afterRender fires once when infuser renders the loadingTemplate and then once when the actual external template is loaded. So even though I have set the option in my config:

infuser.defaults.useLoadingTemplate = false;

it still fires twice except now with an empty template. What this does mean is I can do this (all my afterRender does is show the modal window once the template has been loaded into it and resize to the content).

Turning async off just to get around the double event firing is probably not ideal.

TEMPLATE

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: template().name(), data: template().data(), afterRender: renderComplete }"></div>
```

VIEW MODEL

```
var renderComplete = function (params) {

  if (params.length > 0) {

     //Do my stuff here.

  }

};
```

If there's a better way or I have done something obviously wrong please let me know :)

Comment: Thank you for that info. I will take that on board the next time I get a problem with the template. Fortunately the project in question has been put on the back burner for now, but I have your suggestion if the project comes back to life.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a different AMD library for KO, one written by the author.

https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-amd-helpers

Mine is not the most elegant solution, but it worked. What I did was add an afterRender call to all of my templates with a setTimeout(callback,100).  The callback sets a jQuery deferred to resolve.  When deferred is resolved, I know all my rendering is done and can execute my code.

```
// create a jQuery deferred
var dfd = $.Deferred();

// in my template call
afterRender: function () {

  // clear the timeout if it's still in play
  if (renderTimeoutId !== undefined) {
      clearTimeout(renderTimeoutId);
  }

  // create a new timeout and restart the clock
  renderTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
      dfd.resolve();
  }, 100);
}

// when my code is complete
dfd.done(function(){ /* after rendering code */});
```

I'm very interested in having a more elegant solution to this, I really don't like having my code depend on timeouts, but it was the best I could come up with at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do not-so-ugly, quick fix of this bug. It seems, that first "afterRender" callback is fired, after render of externalTemplateEngine "loading" div. So quick fix is to check what elements has been rendered:

```
afterRender = function (params) {
    // console.log(params);
    if (params.length <= 0 || $(params[0]).hasClass('infuser-loading'))
        return;

    // ... your code goes here
}
```